# HTML5 Multiple Video Display - Hover Over to Play

Tags: html, video, hover, ogg

Okay so I have followed a good tutorial regarding embedding videos via HTML5 video tag, which can be found [here](http://developer.practicalecommerce.com/articles/1878-Hover-to-Play-Ecommerce-Videos-with-HTML5-CSS-and-JavaScript).  Basically the idea is that on hover the video plays, on hover out it stops playing.

Well, I've been trying to include multiple videos on one page (all the same video, mind you) in hopes that I could create a sort of interactive multi-tiled board of sorts.  In other words, you hover over each video, it creates varying images based on where in each video you end up, etc.

Whatever, the question I am asking is:  based on this tutorial that I've followed, what is the best way to create multiple, tiled videos?  I'll paste the code I've been working with.  The problem I'm having is that if I create multiple javascript functions, it shows only the video of the last function I've created, rather than all videos.

I hope this makes sense. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ymV8J/10/) is the link to what I've been working on so far.  NOTE: the video takes a while to load, so until then it will play the sound but no image.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution I found:
The only warning I give you is to set the videos to preload="none" because if they all load it will be nightmare  on your bandwidth.  I had to switch mine and now I am looking for a solution to let people know a video is loading.

```
var vid = document.getElementsByTagName("video");
[].forEach.call(vid, function (item) {
    item.addEventListener('mouseover', hoverVideo, false);
    item.addEventListener('mouseout', hideVideo, false);
});

function hoverVideo(e)
{   
    this.play();
}
function hideVideo(e)
{
    this.pause();
}
```

Here is where I got the answer: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/281583-video-plays-on-mouse-over-but-not-with-multiple-videos/

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that's looking to achieve this using jQuery, here's a solution that I use for dynamically loaded content:

```
        //play video on hover
        $(document).on('mouseover', 'video', function() { 
            $(this).get(0).play(); 
        }); 

        //pause video on mouse leave
        $(document).on('mouseleave', 'video', function() { 
            $(this).get(0).pause(); 
        });
```

This can be used for a page with 1 - N videos, and only the hovered video will play at each time, while each will pause on the current frame on mouseleave.

Here's an example of it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/cc7w0pda/

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it's easy to understand

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<video id="vv" width="500" height="500" controls onmouseout="this.pause()" onmouseover="this.play()">
<source src="xx.mp4">
Your browser does not support this file
</video>
</html>
```